# Can I extend VS Code TextMate Language Grammars?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, textmate

Is there a way to **extend the default [`csharp.tmLanguage`](https://github.com/dotnet/csharp-tmLanguage)** with some additional rule? With references to existing scopes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can **include a grammar** just like:

```
{ "include": "source.cs" }
```

But if you replace the grammar with your own (defining your own `source.cs` scope), then you cannot include the original `source.cs` scope anymore into it (VS Code reports it failed tokenize the file).

Visual Studio Code supports **[grammar injection](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2793#issuecomment-221093247)**, like:

```
"grammars": [
            {
                "scopeName": "source.todo",
                "path": "./syntaxes/todo.json",
                "injectTo": [  "source.js", "source.ts" ]
            },
```

Which is surprisingly under documented. It works, but you can inject into existing scopes, except the top level `source` scope. Also, it seems to me you can inject **additions** only, instead override rules. So again, I cannot extend grammar this way.

---

For now I go with **a workaround, where I contribute 2 grammars**. One is the original C# grammar with a fake name, the 2nd is the overwriting C# grammar, including all the original rules via the fake scope. I wish there was a way without this.

This way I can add some rules "before" I include the original grammar. But still, these are additions, I cannot really extend existing rules.

Comment: Hello!
I'm trying to do the same thing, but without results, can you please post your package json with multiple grammars definition?

Comment: Sure, take a look at [**eppz! (C# theme for Unity)**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eppz.eppz-code) sources.